# Elasticsearch. Nested query for nested in nested

Tags: php, elasticsearch, nested

My mapping is (part of it):

```
$index =  [
"mappings" => [
    "goods" => [
        "dynamic_templates"=> [
                        [
                            "iattribute_id"=> [
                                "match_mapping_type"=> "string",
                                "match"=>   "attribute_id",
                                "mapping"=> [
                                    "type"=> "integer"
                                ]
                            ]
                        ],
                        [
                            "iattribute_value"=> [
                                "match_mapping_type"=> "string",
                                "match"=>   "attribute_value",
                                "mapping"=> [
                                    "type"=> "string",
                                    "index" => "not_analyzed"
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],
        "properties" => [
            ...
            "individual_attributes" => [
                            "type" => "nested",
                            "properties" => [
                                "template_id" => ["type" => "integer"],
                                "attributes_set" => [
                                    "type" => "nested",
                                    "properties" => [
                                        "attribute_id" => ["type" => "integer"],
                                        "attribute_value" => ["type" => "string", "index" => "not_analyzed"]
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
            ...
        ]
    ]
]
];
```

How can I query `attribute_id` and `attribute_value`? They are nested inside nested. I can't understand how to specify path to fields.
I've composed query but it doesn't work.

```
GET /index/type/_search
{
"query" : {
  "nested" : {
    "path" : "individual_attributes.attributes_set",
    "score_mode" : "none",
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term" : {
                "individual_attributes.attributes_set.attribute_id": "20"
              }
            },
            {
              "term" : {
                "individual_attributes.attributes_set.attribute_value": "commodi"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "individual_attributes",
      "score_mode": "none",
      "filter": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "individual_attributes.attributes_set",
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "term": {
                    "individual_attributes.attributes_set.attribute_id": "20"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "term": {
                    "individual_attributes.attributes_set.attribute_value": "commodi"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work...Maby something wrong with my mapping. GET /index/_mapping/type provides me the following - laravel.io/bin/8KW8v

Comment: If that's your mapping, you have a bit more serious issues with the index. The mapping doesn't contain `nested` fields, as per your mapping in php. So, either the index is not created the you think it is in your php code, or that mapping belongs to a different index.

Comment: I'm not able to view that mapping (laravel.io/bin/fork/yGvY6) unless I give read permissions to my private email address in github. And I'm not going to do that. But, as I said, the mapping I'm seeing in **laravel.io/bin/8KW8v** doesn't match the one you have in your php code. There's nothing more to add to that. You need to fix your mapping so that those fields are `nested`. And then the query I suggested will work.

Comment: It seems that your variant of code is correct. I haven't checked yet, but that's why I think so. I've created mapping via sense in my browser, and execution of GET /index/_mapping/type gives me correct mapping. But when I create the same mapping via php it gives me [] (emptyness). Something wrong with my php. I'll check what exactly and then I'll check your code. P.S. I haven't seen your comment when I've been writing mine. Yes, I'll check mapping.

Comment: I have json code for sense in browser - creation of mapping is succeed. I use the same code (json_decode($json_string,1)) in my php and something goes wrong.

Comment: Yes. There was a problem with my php. And yes, your query is working. Thanks a lot.